# problem matching word in list read in from text file

Tags: python

When I execute the following code, for some reason I don't get a match on some of the words and I'm not sure why.
Here is the copy of the text which is read in (it is 5 words each followed by a newline character as follows):

File:

```
cackle
cage 
cake
calibrate
call
```

Code:

```
verb_list = set()
with open ("/Users/docs/verbs") as f:
    for item in f:
        verb_list.add(item)
    print("verbs: " + str(len(verb_list)))
if ("call\n" in verb_list):
    print("true")
else:
    print("false")
if ("cage\n" in verb_list):
    print("true")
else:
    print("false")
```

Output:

```
verbs: 5
true
false
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: you got a extra space after cage

Comment: See, there is an extra space in cage : ```'cage '```. You can do ```verbs.add(item.strip("\n").strip())```. Also, ```verb_list``` is undefined.

Comment: The variable `verb_list` is not defined in this code, so it should result in an error. Replace it with `verbs`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cage has an extra space after it. Also verb_list is not defined. Try using verbs.

Comment: verb_list was just a typo as I simplified and copied the code from the original project (which I'll fix). However it looks like the extra spaces were the issue